# sql select show issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

```
SELECT nom AS Nom, id_type_produit, id_format 
FROM dbo.Produits
```

this only show me the id of  `id_type` and `id_Format` i need to show the  value of them (  in 2 other  table,  like  id_format = 1 = 750 ml )   and type  = 1 = wine..

but when i do the select i only see the 1  and 2 i dont see the  750 ml and wine

Comment: What are the other two tables (that contain the values of type and format) called?

Comment: dbo.type_produits and dbo_formats

Comment: Please add tables structures (of all 3 tables), example data, expected output and where you are stuck right now.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT nom AS Nom, Produits.id_type_produit, type_produits.value, Produits.id_format, formats.value
FROM dbo.Produits
INNER JOIN dbo.type_produits ON Produits.id_type_produit = type_produits.id_type_produit
INNER JOIN dbo.dbo_formats ON Produits.id_format = formats.id_format
```